# Openlayers 3 - if else, check if layer is visible condition

Tags: openlayers

I am building an interactive map where my layers are displayed by zoomlevels using the min/maxResolution property. Here's the simple JS:

```
function getmap(){

//BaseLayer
    function baseMap(){ 
        var baseMap= new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({ 
            url:'http://{1-
            4}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            })
        })
        return baseMap
    };
//MainLayer
    var layerSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var urlSecteur = 'JsonUrl&' 
        +'bbox='+ extent.join(',');
        $.ajax({
          url: urlSecteur,
          success: function(data) {
            var features = geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(data);
            layerSource .addFeatures(features);
          }
        }); 
      },
      strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });

   function createLayer(){
            var Layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'Layer',
                source: LayerSource,
                minResolution: 0,
                maxResolution: 1
            })
     return Layer
  };


//Assembly of layers
    var layerBaseMap= baseMap(); 
    var layerLayer = createLayer();


    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
        layerBaseMap,
        layerLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.52639, 46.48361]),
            zoom: 6,
            minZoom: 6,
            minZoom: 6
        })
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <!-- Javascript library "openlayer" -->
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/JsLib/openlayer/ol.css" />
             <script src="/JsLib/openlayer/ol.js"></script>
         <!-- Javascript library "JQuery" -->
             <script src="/JsLib/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
         <!-- Link JS -->
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/mapol.js"> </script>
    </head>

 <body  onload="getmap()">

       <div id="legend">
            <div id="attribute1">
            </div>
            <div id="attribute2">
            </div>
            <div id="attribute3">
            </div>
        </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

<style>

#map { 
    height: 810px;
    width: 1380px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 106px;
    left: 300px;
}

#legend{
    display: none;
}

#attribute1{
    background-color:rgb(254, 237, 222);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;   
    position: relative;
}
#attribute2{
    background-color:rgb(253,208,162);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    }
#attribute3{
    background-color:rgb(253,174,107);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    }

</style>

  </body>

</html>
```

What I want to do is to display a legend when the layer gets visible (when the user reach the appropriate zoomlevel). The legend is already set in HTML so I just need to change the display property in CSS from "none" to "block". 
In theory this should goes like this at the end of the Js:

```
   if(layerLayer.isVisible == true){
            legend.style.display="block"
       }else{
        legend.style.display="none"
       };
```

I have already tried some solutions, noone of these has worked:

```
if(layerLayer.getVisible() == true){
        legend.style.display="block"
    }else{
        legend.style.display="none"
    };
```

And

```
if(layerSource.getState() == 'ready'){
        legend.style.display="block"
    }else{
        legend.style.display="none"
    };
```

Both display the legend when the map gets loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Need detailed code. where the condition code exist? on event?

Comment: I've added a detailed code, I hope it becomes clearer. The condition needs to be add at the end of the JS it could be on event, I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: by the way, you set min/maxResolution but user can move out of the resolutions?

Comment: Yes, when the map gets loaded, the user start at "minZoom: 6" as defined in "var map = new ol.Map" and then he can zoom forth and back afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change:resolution` event on the view. Then, compare `minResolution` with `currentResolution`

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function() {
  var minRes = map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getMinResolution(); // map layer
  var curRes = map.getView().getResolution(); // current resolution

  if (minRes < curRes) {
    legend.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    legend.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

sample codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weoRWG)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chase Choi, I didn't used your method, but part of it. I dispalyed the  legend based on the current resolution, it work fine:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function() {
  var curRes = map.getView().getResolution(); // current resolution

  if (curRes < 6 && curRes > 1) {
    legend.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    legend.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```